# Does es2023 exists as compilerOption in tsconfig or how to use Array.prototype.findLast?

Tags: typescript

In my tsconfig I have

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2022",
      "dom"
    ],
```

Now I use [Array.prototype.findLast](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLast) in my code, [which exists in the browsers which are relevant for me](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_findlast).

Typescript failes on it:

```
Property 'findLast' does not exist on type 'Unit[]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2023' or later.
```

But when I change es2022 to es2023 in tsconfig as above eslint complains with

```
ESLint: Parsing error: Invalid value for lib provided: es2023
```

[And indeed, the lib seems not to exist at the moment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#high-level-libraries).

But how can Typescript recommend an option which does not even exist? And how can I use findLast without tsignore?

--

Typescript Version: ~5.1.6

Eslint: ^8.18.0 (current 8.56.0 in fact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest TypeScript (v5.3.3 as I write this), `lib` has both `"ES2023"` and `"ESNext"` options, and both have `findLast`, so: `lib: ["ES2023", "DOM"]`. It's true [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) doesn't mention ES2023 (yet), but the docs tend to lag behind a bit. Looking at the [commit history](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commits/main/src/lib/es2023.array.d.ts) for `es2023.array.d.ts`, `findLast` was added in January 2023 (I'm surprised the file already existed that long ago). So if you update TypeScript, you should be good to go.

---

If for some reason you can't update to the latest TypeScript, as a temporary workaround you could have your own `*.d.ts` file adding `findLast` (for instance, `temporary-array-2023.d.ts`):

```
// TEMPORARY WORKAROUND
interface Array<T> {
    findLast<S extends T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S | undefined;
    findLast(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T | undefined;
}
```

If that's in your source directories, TypeScript will merge it with the built-in `Array` interface.

But you can get rid of that when you can update TypeScript.